# unit testing legacy code

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm new to unit testing and trying to unit test the model validation of an old zend application which is using forms.

Inside one of the forms it creates an instance of a second class and I'm struggling to understand how I can mock the dependent object. The form reads as follows :

```
class Default_Form_Timesheet extends G10_Form {

  public function init() {
  parent::init();

  $this->addElement( 'hidden', 'idTimesheet', array( 'filters' => array ('StringTrim' ), 'required' => false, 'label' => false ) );
  $this->addElement('checkbox', 'storyFilter', array('label' => 'Show my stories'));


  $user = new Default_Model_User();
  $this->addElement('select', 'idUser', array('filters' => array('StringTrim'), 'class' => 'idUser', 'required' => true, 'label' => 'User'));
  $this->idUser->addMultiOption("","");
  $this->idUser->addMultiOptions($user->fetchDeveloper());
  ...
  ......
```

My problem occurs when the call is made to $user->fetchDeveloper(). I suspect it has something todo with mocking objects and dependency injection but any guidence would be appreciated. My Failing unit test reads as follows...

```
require_once TEST_PATH . '/ControllerTestCase.php';

class TimesheetValidationTest extends ControllerTestCase {

  public $Timesheet;
  public $UserStub;
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->Timesheet = new Default_Model_Timesheet();
    parent::setUp();
  }

  /**
  * @dataProvider timesheetProvider
  */
  public function testTimesheetValid( $timesheet ) {

    $UserStub = $this->getMock('Default_Model_User', array('fetchDeveloper'));
    $UserStub->expects( $this->any() )
      ->method('fetchDeveloper')
      ->will( $this->returnValue(array(1 => 'Mickey Mouse')));

    $Timesheet = new Default_Model_Timesheet();
    $this->assertEquals(true, $Timesheet->isValid( $timesheet ) );
  }
```

My data provider is in a separate file.

It is terminating at the command line with no output and I'm a bit stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could mock `init()`, or you need to make sure the external class will be found

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The User class is being found, it's the called to "fetchDeveloper" that appears to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mock the `Default_Model_User` class in your test for the form.  Because your code is instantiating the class internally you are not able to replace it with a mock.

You have a couple of options for testing this code.

You look into what `fetchDeveloper` is doing and control what it is returning.  Either via a mock object that you can inject somewhere (looks unlikely) or by setting some data so that you know what the data will be.  This will make your test a little brittle in that it could break when the data you are using changes.

The other option is to refactor the code so that you can pass the mock into your form.  You can set a constructor that would allow you to set the `Default_Model_User` class and then you would be able to mock it with your test as written.

The constructor would like like this:

```
class Default_Form_Timesheet extends G10_Form {
    protected $user;

    public function __construct($options = null, Default_Model_User $user = null){
        if(is_null($user)) {
            $user = new Default_Model_User();
        }
        $this->user = $user;
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

Zend Framework allows options to be passed to forms constructor which I am not sure if you use in your code anywhere so this should not break any of your current functionality.  When can then pass an optional `Default_Model_User` again so as to not break your current functionality.  You need to set the values for `$this->user` before calling `parent::__construct` otherwise Zend will throw an error.

Now your init function will have to change from:

```
$user = new Default_Model_User();
```

to

```
$user = $this->user;
```

In your test you can now pass in your mock object and it will be used.

```
public function testTimesheetValid( $timesheet ) {

    $UserStub = $this->getMock('Default_Model_User', array('fetchDeveloper'));
    $UserStub->expects( $this->any() )
      ->method('fetchDeveloper')
      ->will( $this->returnValue(array(1 => 'Mickey Mouse')));

    $Timesheet = new Default_Model_Timesheet(null, $UserStub);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $Timesheet->isValid( $timesheet ) );
}
```

Creating a mock doesn't replace the object so that when `new` is called that your mock object is created.  It creates a new object that extends your class that you can now pass around.  `new` is a death to testability.

Comment: While I think it makes sense to change code in order to gain better testability, I think this the wrong answer on "How to test some legacy code". I would have searched for a way to test this without changing the code. I'm just mentioning this. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl I gave two options.  One allowed for not changing the code (use data that is available and don't try to mock things), the other involved changing the code.

Comment: `Because your code is instantiating the class internally you are not able to replace it with a mock.` .. But you can mock the method(s) itself. However, the interesting code is missing in the question

Comment: @hek2mgl: You can mock which method? `Default_Form_Timesheet::init()`? That's the method you're trying to test. You can't mock the method you're trying to test...then you wouldn't be testing it. You can't mock the `fetchDeveloper()` method, because you can't mock the object it's being called on. I don't get what you're suggesting. Can you provide your own solution that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: I told, I need to see the code. Where do you see that `init()` is the method to be tested? Me not. Why shouldn't it being possible to mock `fetchDeveloper()`? (Look carefully, its actually being mocked)

Comment: `init()` gets called in the constructor of the form.  In order to test the `isValid`, you will need to have the options set properly, hence mocking `fetchDeveloper()` which isn't being mocked in the original test due to the class being instantiated in the `init` function (the mock doesn't get passed anywhere to be used).  Mocking the `init()` function would cause problems with trying to compare the values and would lead to mocking many other Zend Framework Form methods making the test much more complicated.